# why I can't find the chat?

Tags: support

I click on "chat" at the top right, but it does not let me enter to any chat

I just get this page:
[image]

then I don't know what to do.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the name of the room to chat in it - "The Frying Pan" is our site's chat room.

Comment: thank you very much